# Syncing output of OpenGL FBO

Tags: opengl, fbo

I'm doing a little bit of video processing in real time using OpenGL.

I do a render to texture via FBO+RBO and shaders for simple processing on the video frame. Then I use that texture to render (not blit) to the default frame buffer.

Some of my video processing needs to be frame accurate. If I step through the video frame by frame everything looks good; when I play it back at video rate it gets out of sync.

I'm thinking that the texture I'm getting out of the FBO+RBO is not based on the texture I input because of buffering/other issues.

This seems like a relevant question but there is no answer to it yet: [double buffering with FBO+RBO and glFinish()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608337/double-buffering-with-fborbo-and-glfinish)

In my case I am using a Qt QGLWidget with the QGL::DoubleBuffer format option.

I need to flush the output of FBO; alternatively if I could work out which frame texture has come out of the FBO I can compensate for the sync issue.